# What is the best way to apply a function to a list of lists in R? specifically if the internal variables are all called the same thing

Tags: r, nested-lists

Hi I am fairly new to R and would appreciate any help on this one.

I have searched for similar questions but I unfortunately I dont really understand the solutions given.

My problem:

I have about 60 excel sheets full of repeated testing data that I want to analyse and compare. These all have a similar structure and variable/column names but the number of data points is different for each one.
I have loaded these into R as a list of lists and I want to perform a series of manipulations on each original data set once it is inside the list of lists. These manipulations would be identical using the same variable names etc but applied to different data sets.

As an example say I wanted to calculate something based on the data and then add the results as a new variable inside the nested list.

A simplified version of my situation would be something like this.

```
###set up###

specimen1=list("Stress"=50:100,
"Strain"=5:55) #represents my excel sheet imports
specimen2=list("Stress"=65:115,
"Strain"=6.5:56.5) #simplifed for brevity

specimen3=list("Stress"=42:92,"Strain"=4.2:54.2)

rate1=list(specimen1,specimen2,specimen3) #my list of lists

names(rate1)<-c("specimen 1","specimen 2","specimen 3") #set the names
```

```
####performing calculation and adding to the list entry###

#now i want to perform a calculation on each specimen and then add the result to that specimen
#I suspect the solution lies with the lapply family something like this?

example_function<-function(Stress,Strain){

E=Stress/Strain #performs calculation
#but doesn't add the result to the list?

rate1$specimen$E=E #something like this to add to the original data set?
#but I don't understand how to change the indexing with out using a for loop

}


lapply(rate1,example_function)
```

#########

What is the best way to perform a function on each element of list of lists which then adds a variable to all those list components?

I suspect that the solution to this will be simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not tied to doing this in `lists`, you can bind all your lists and do it in the resulting `data.frame` format using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(rate1, .id="specimen") %>% 
 mutate(E = Stress/Strain)
```

which produces

```
# A tibble: 153 x 4
   specimen   Stress Strain     E
   <chr>       <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 specimen 1     50      5 10   
 2 specimen 1     51      6  8.5 
 3 specimen 1     52      7  7.43
 4 specimen 1     53      8  6.62
...
```

Using `data.frames` is usually the most straightforward way of doing things in `R`.

If you want to keep using `lists`, because you have to make a new column, it's possibly better to use a `for` loop instead of `lapply`. This is how you solve your particular issue using a loop.

```
# this will add the column E to each element of the list rate1
for(i in 1:length(rate1)) {
  rate1[[i]]$E <- rate1[[i]]$Stress/rate1[[i]]$Strain  
}
```

This is the version with `lapply`, you can keep adding columns inside the `list` call of the `function(li)`.

```
modified_rate1 <- 
lapply(rate1, function(li) 
  list(
    Stress = li$Stress,
    Strain = li$Strain,
    E = li$Stress/li$Strain
  )
)
```

I think doing this in a `data.frame` is the way to go, but you should see what's better for your other many purposes

Comment: Great thanks for your clear and speedy reply. All three of those options seem to work. 
I will look at using data frames again. I had started out with them but had problems when some of my other code required initalizing an empty data.table with dynamic column lengths.

Comment: Depending on your data structure, a `data.frame` can work with variables of different lengths (check the long format of `tidyr`). Otherwise, keep using `lists`. If the answer works, consider accepting it.

Comment: @woodbutcher Also, if the answer was useful, consider accepting it